# jQuery: set if else statement to perform offset based on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, parallax

Finishing up a parallax, one page site and I've got a fixed nav, so I have to offset the various div's / sections on my page so they don't get cut off on top. Problem is performing this for different browser widths, since my fixed nav will be about half the height on mobile as it is on desktop.

Trying this jQuery out and it only seems to perform the else action, not the if. So the offset is too much on mobile. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.main-navigation a[href^="http://example.com/#"]' ).click(function() {
      if (jQuery(window).width() < 677) {
        jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing', offset:-20 });
      } else {
        jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing', offset:-141 });
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will provide a more responsive solution:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.resizeContentHeight = function(){
        $('#main-content').css("margin-top", $(".header-fixed").height());
    }
$(window).load(function() {
    $.resizeContentHeight();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $.resizeContentHeight();
});
});
```

In this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gapugs8u/1/) I calculate the height of the `.header-fixed` and apply that as a `margin-top` to the content below it (`#main-content`). I think this is what you are trying to achieve right? I have tested this and modified it to work across multiple browsers. Not sure if this will be relevant in a parallax site if you could provide examples of the HTML you are working with it would help. This will also adjust if the user changes the orientation of their device.

This could also be adapted to add or remove the height of the header to the anchor links.

Comment: Kind of but I'm using Pure Drawer for the navigation and scrollTo for the parallax effects. So your example doesn't really work for me here.

The site is password protected, so I can't show you the page now. And since there's so many external scripts involved, I can't really link to those from a JSFiddle either. And yours didn't seem to work. No JS in it.